# SQL SELECT WITH SUBQUERY IN HAVING

Tags: sql, oracle, count, oracle-sqldeveloper, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to do task 'For each department (give the number) list the people who have worked in the most projects'

I'm working with Oracle test data (EMP, DEPT, PROJ, PROJ_EMP)
, so far i tried this

```
SELECT e.ename, d.deptno, COUNT(*)
FROM PROJ p, EMP e, PROJ_EMP pe, dept d
WHERE e.empno = pe.empno AND pe.projno = p.projno AND d.deptno=e.deptno
GROUP BY e.ename, d.deptno
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT LICZBA_PROJEKTOW
FROM 
(SELECT e.ename, COUNT(*) LICZBA_PROJEKTOW
FROM PROJ p, EMP e, PROJ_EMP pe
WHERE e.empno = pe.empno AND pe.projno = p.projno
GROUP BY e.ename) PROJEKTY
WHERE PROJEKTY.ename = e.ename);
```

but i only get this result:

```
ENAME          PROJNO        SAL
---------- ---------- ----------
SCOTT               1       3000
KING                2       5000
FORD                3       3000
SCOTT               3       3000
FORD                4       3000
SCOTT               5       3000
```

any advices what i'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
by the advise i used inner joins, getting same output as aerlier

```
SELECT e.ename, d.deptno, COUNT(*) ILE_PROJEKTOW
FROM EMP e
INNER JOIN DEPT d ON d.deptno=e.deptno
INNER JOIN PROJ_EMP pe ON e.empno = pe.empno
INNER JOIN PROJ p ON pe.projno = p.projno
GROUP BY e.ename, d.deptno;
```

which conditions i have provide to get expected output? (it has to be having subquery)

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Your query and result do not relate. As a starter, the output column in the query and in the result are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select e.ename, e.deptno, count(*) as cnt_projects
        rank() over(partition by e.deptno order by count(*) desc) rn
    from proj_emp pe 
    inner join proj p on p.projno = pe.projno
    inner join emp  e on e.empno  = pe.empno
    group by e.empno, e.ename, e.deptno
) t
where rn = 1
```

For each department, this brings the employee with most projects - top ties included, if any.

Notes:

- Use explicit joins! Implicit joins are legacy syntax, that should not be used in new code
- You don't need table `dept` to get the results you want; if you needed to display something like the department name instead of just its number, then you would typically join that table, and add the relevant column(s) to the `select` and `group by` clauses

---

If you really want to do this with `having`, then you would use a correlated subquery with a row-limiting clause:

```
select e.ename, e.deptno, count(*) as cnt_projects
from proj_emp pe 
inner join proj p on p.projno = pe.projno
inner join emp  e on e.empno  = pe.empno
group by e.empno, e.ename, e.deptno
having count(*) = (
    select count(*)
    from proj_emp pe1
    inner join proj p1 on p1.projno = pe1.projno
    inner join emp  e1 on e1.empno  = pe1.empno
    where e1.deptno = e.deptno
    group by e1.empno
    fetch first 1 row only
)
```

Comment: your output is correct, but I have to use subquery in having

Comment: @toom122: see my update. This solution is less efficient though.